# Adapt PHP form action for WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a PHP form that I'd like to adapt for WordPress. I went through and made a plugin that creates a widget and a form. The form action goes to a file I created called `listrak-newsletter-api.php` but when I submit to it in the below form, I get a 404 error.

These files are all located in my `/wp-content/plugins/listrak-newsletter-api` directory.

Stand alone, outside of WordPress, this works great. But since migrating it into WordPress, it's becoming quite convoluted. I used to have a simple HTML page with a form that had a form action to `listrak-newsletter-api.php` and that worked great. But taking this into WordPress seems to have made it a little more difficult than it should be.

Now, I want to keep it as a widget because I'm able to place the widget where I want, on the sidebar, of the WordPress theme. Where it shows up and how it shows up when I activate it are great. Functionality just needs to work.

This file is `/wp-content/plugins/listrak-newsletter-api/plugin.php` :

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: Listrak Newsletter API
* Description: Newsletter integration with Listrak.
* Version: 1.0
*/

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget()
{
    register_widget('wpb_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');

// Creating the widget 
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
            'wpb_widget', 
        // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 
        // Widget description
            array(
            'description' => __('Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wpb_widget_domain')
        ));
    }

    // Creating widget front-end

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];        

        // This is where you run the code and display the output
        echo '<div class="block-title"><span>EMAIL NEWSLETTER</span></div>';
        echo '<form action="/wp-content/plugins/listrak-newsletter-api.php" method="post">';
        echo '  <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email"><label>Email</label>';
        echo '  <input class="email" name="email" required="" type="email"></div>';     
        echo '  <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button"><input class="tnp-submit" value="Subscribe now!" type="submit"></div>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form($instance)
    {
        if (isset($instance['title'])) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            $title = __('New title', 'wpb_widget_domain');
        }
        // Widget admin form
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_id('title');
        ?>"><?php
                _e('Title:');
        ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_id('title');
        ?>" name="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_name('title');
        ?>" type="text" value="<?php
                echo esc_attr($title);
        ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance          = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_widget ends here

?>
```

This file is `/wp-content/plugins/listrak-newsletter-api/listrak-newsletter-api.php` :

```
<?php

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email']; //obtain email from post, place into $email variable
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); //sanitizing email
    //$theAction = $_POST['action'];
    //wpSubscription($host, $email, $theAction);
    //$redirect = $_POST['redirect'];
    //header('Location: ' . $redirect);    

    if ($_POST['email'] == '') {
        echo "Please enter an email address";
    }
    if ($host == network_site_url()) {
        $sh_param   = array( //setting username & password array
            'UserName' => "",
            'Password' => ""
        );
        $authvalues = new SoapVar($sh_param, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT); //encoding username and password array
        $headers[]  = new SoapHeader("http://webservices.listrak.com/v31/", 'WSUser', $sh_param);
        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://webservices.listrak.com/v31/IntegrationService.asmx?WSDL", array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
        ));

        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
        $params = array( //parameters for soap xml integration with listrak
            'WSContact' => array(
                'EmailAddress' => $email,
                'ListID' => ''
            ),
            'ProfileUpdateType' => 'Overwrite',
            'ExternalEventIDs' => '',
            'OverrideUnsubscribe' => true
        );

        try {

            $rest = $soapClient->SetContact($params); //using SetContact method, send parameters

        }
        catch (SoapFault $e) { //if an error occurs, display it

            echo '<pre>';

            print($e->getMessage());

            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't know upto what degree you want to keep your old form because if it is a contact form you need, plugins like contact form 7 or ninja forms will do the trick with less pain.

Nevertheless, if you want to keep your form and the php logic behind it, first condier how that form will work:

The three following cases need you to create a child theme so your changes are not swept away after an update of the theme.

**Case 1) After submitting you end in a different page.**

You create a new template for the page that will take care of processing the form, and then you create a new page and assign it the template you just created.

This template will have the php to get the posted values and store them or send them by email, and will set some output as OK or ERROR.

In the page you can customize the content part or do everything in the template.

**2) After submitting you stay on the same page (reloading it).**

Here you will need to copy the template provided by the theme which is used for the page where you put the form to the child-theme, and make changes to add the processing of the form.

**3) Stay on the same page and handle the submition with ajax.**

Here you will have to setup a wp_ajax_* handler to get the data sent using jQuery most likely, and process the data inthe handler. Finally show some ok, or error message delivered from the handler to ajax call.

For any of these to work you will also have to use wp_enqueue_scripts and wp_enqueue_styles, to serve the css and javascript needed for your implementations to work.